# Why is DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable final?

Tags: spring-security

I'm using the DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable (in Spring Security 3.2.4), but found it a bit unwieldy. It does not delegate the implementation of toString(). Also, there is no getter for the delegate.

I'm not sure I understand why it's a final class, preventing easy work-arounds/extensions. As it stands now, I have to have my own wrapper around DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable, with extra copies of its fields.

Thoughts?

Jürgen

Comment: See http://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2681 and http://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2682.